# Returning playlists on custom Google Home app

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

I've made a web-app that allows churches to make YouTube playlists of the songs they're doing on Sunday.

I've written a Google Assistant intent that accepts input like "Play the songs we're doing this weekend on my television."

This intent makes use of a webhook, asking my server to look up the songs and hymns for the church in question. My server successfully returns a URL of a YouTube Playlist.

However, it is just reading the playlist URL back because I don't know the way to communicate to actions to show the URL on Chromecast.

When asking Google Support for help, I was told:

> Yes, there is a way to send a YouTube URL to Chromecast, or a song-name/artist-name to Google Play or Spotify using a webhook. If you trigger intents via events (as described at https://api.ai/docs/events#invoking_event_from_webhook), you should be able to see a response defined in such intent in the Actions on Google test console. It may look like this:
>
> User via test console -> Query request -> Intent A -> Webhook -> Web service logic -> Event is sent back to API.AI -> Intent B -> Response defined in Intent B is shown in test console.
>
> Let us know if this helps or if it's different from what you are trying to accomplish.

Unfortunately, I have not been able to decipher the meaning of the above quote.

Thanks.

UPDATE FROM GOOGLE:

> Hi Jason,
>
> Sorry you can't use your app to interact with inbuilt music apps. Alternate option is to provide a link to the user in the Google Assistant that opens the app a user wants to use. Hope this helps!
>
> Thanks,
> Lalitha
> Actions on Google Support Team

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer your specific question, about Chromecast, that feature is not available for third party apps. You will not be able to stream the music directly.

Comment: Interesting that I was told the opposite by Google. I've updated my question to include their full response.

Comment: That is news to me. I haven't seen any documentation, and I'm not sure what that response means.

Comment: Update from Google appending to answer. LOL